# Linear algebra "give vector in opposite direction to V with length 1"

Tags: linear-algebra

So should be a really easy question, but could not figure it out.

```
Plane V: (x, y, z) = (1, -1, -1) + scalar1(3, -1, 4) + scalar2(3, 2, 0)

vector v = (-8, 12, 9)
```

Should use dot product I guess: $\vec{a} \cdot \vec{b} = |a| |b| \cos \theta$. $\cos(180) = -1$ and with size of vector as $1$, the result of the dot product should be $-1$.

```
How would you find a vector opposite to vector v, size 1?
```

Comment: By opposite do you mean $-v$? If yes, just take $w=-v/\|v\|$.

Comment: Sigur's comment is the whole answer, but I still wonder what has that plane above to do at all with the question...?

Comment: @DonAntonio Maybe he wants the answer within the plane defined by those three points?

Comment: Maybe he wants to reflect $v$ w.r.t. the plane $V$. Bad idea to name both with $v,V$.

Comment: Maybe...who knows? But for that it should be that $\,v\,$ belongs to the plane...does it? And anyway, if it does then also does $\,\pm\frac{1}{||v||}v\,$ ...

Comment: @DonAntanio If it is a plane, are the three points in it, or are the "scalar1" and "scalar2" shift points from $(1,-1,-1)$?

Comment: Lets wait some edit by the owner.

Comment: @adamW, scalars are scalars, and for any other point in $\,\,Bbb R^3\,$ we can check whether it belongs to the plane by equating the point coordinates to the given vectorial equation and finding out whether there are two scalars that satisfy *the three* resulting equations. Try this with the direction vectors..:)

Answer (score 1):

Before editing the question into latex, I think it is this. The plane $V$ is any

$$ \pmatrix{x & y & z} \quad\text{such that} \quad    \pmatrix{x & y & z} = \pmatrix{s_1 & s_2} \pmatrix{3 & -1 & 4 \\ 3 & 2 & 0} + \pmatrix{1 & -1 & -1}$$
 For any $s_1$ and $s_2$

His vector $\mathbf{v}$ need not be in the plane for the original question to make sense.

```
Could the OP verify and use my Latex to reformat the question.
(right click on the equation to see the formatting text,
put $ symbols or $$ symbols both before and after to make
it work in your post) 

For example this $$\mathbf{v}=\pmatrix{x & y & z}$$ gives
```

$$\mathbf{v}=\pmatrix{x & y & z}$$

**Without more clarifying details, no one will be able to help with an answer.**

Answer (score 0):

It's easy to verify that $\overrightarrow{u}=-\frac{\overrightarrow{v}}{||\overrightarrow{v}||}$ is a vector opposite to $\overrightarrow{u}$ with size 1.